# SQL tables not populating from Python?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, timescaledb

I'm having trouble getting my tables I setup to populate from an API I connected to with Python. On my python terminal it shows that the data is being inserted into the tables, however when I go to check the tables they are still empty.

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(host=config.DB_HOST, port=config.DB_PORT, database=config.DB_NAME, user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASS)
api = tradeapi.REST(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET, base_url=config.API_URL)
assets = api.list_assets()

for asset in assets:
print(f"Inserting stock {asset.name} {asset.symbol}")
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO stock (name, symbol, exchange, is_etf)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, false)
""", (asset.name, asset.symbol, asset.exchange))

connection.commit()
```

When I run the code it returns:

> Inserting stock x

thousands of times as if it is working, but when I go check the database in TablePlus there is still nothing there. I have tried refreshing the the table and database and rerunning the code. I am also using Timescale cloud, and it shows no indication that anything is being added to the table either. How is my Python code running with no issues while nothing is being added to the table?

Comment: The data won't be visible until `connection.commit()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some idea

1. try run your sql in sql tool
2. add a try catch on commit to see if your code works properly and return what seems to be the problem if it's not working. something like this:

---

```
try:
    cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO stock (name, symbol, exchange, is_etf) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, false)

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Failed to insert record into table", error)
```

Comment: The first suggestion is good but the second is not for a few reasons: the question uses postgres and you're showing how to catch `MySQLdb` errors (also not sure if you can catch warnings like that). Also your `execute` call is missing closing quotes & parenthesis. Finally, the question says that no error occurs, so the try/catch logic won't help.

Comment: Ahhh my bad, thanks for the comment

Comment: I came back the next day and my table is now populated. I guess it was working I just needed to wait a bit. I appreciate the help anyway!

Comment: I have tried usig Postgresql and I found a way to catch the error. maybe you could try it if you want